# saving submission.created_utc value and saving in django models.DateTimeField

Tags: django, datetime-format, utc, reddit, praw

Having an issue grabbing the submission.created_utc value and trying to store it in my django models.DateTimeField.

```
// here's my model's DateTimeField
red_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)

// this is how I try to save it
red_created = returnUtcDate(submission.created_utc)
// value of created_utc = 1589720741.0

def returnUtcDate(utcDate):
    dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(utcDate))
    newUtcDate = timezone.make_aware(dt, timezone.utc)

    return newUtcDate  // value being returned 2020-05-17 13:05:41+00:00
```

When I try to run that I get:
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

I know I need to convert the utc date before I store it but I don't know how or to what format. Tried searching but I'm assuming searching for the wrong terms.

Comment: Do you have `USE_TZ` set to `True` or `False`?

Comment: Neither, not sure where to set that @schillingt

Comment: I actually found this on my setting file:
```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: Good, then you don't have to worry as much since Django will automatically convert the datetimes to UTC as long as they are timezone aware. See the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#overview

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Appreciate the help.